# dynamic row to X-Editable

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datatable, x-editable

I am using X-Editable Plugin in Asp.net with jquery Datatables to edit my table. How to add a dynamic row to x-Editable? This is my example:

```
$("#myDataTable").dataTable
       ({  
           ...

           "fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
               for (f = 0; f < nomCol.length; f++) { 
                   if (typeChamp[f] == "text") {
                       $('td:eq(' + f + ')', nRow).editable({
                          ...
                       });
                   }

                   if (typeChamp[f] == "date") {                          
                       $('td:eq(' + f + ')', nRow).editable({
                           ...                              
                       });
                   }

                   if(typeChamp[f]=="select") {
                       $('td:eq(' + f + ')', nRow).editable({
                           ...                               
                       });
                   }
           }
      }
   });
```